# Amazon Web Service EC2 instance RedHat yum does not work

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, yum

After setting up a fresh ec2 instance, I tried to install vim using yum...  I got this error:

ERROR: can not find RHNS CA file: /usr/share/rhn/RHN-ORG-TRUSTED-SSL-CERT

Answer (score 4):

In the folder /usr/share/rhn/ the cert file is named wrong...
you can simply make a copy of the cert with the correct name

(as root)

```
cd /usr/share/rhn/
cp RHNS-CA-CERT RHN-ORG-TRUSTED-SSL-CERT
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a correct way to remedy this issue... if anyone has any information, please post it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34776377/7004398) worked for me.

> `rvm autolibs read-only`
>
> In that way rvm do not try to download the dependencies from redhat. But it tell us what is missing, so we can install what is missing manually with yum install from centos repository.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me was to copy the cert from another server