# how install rvm on RHL7 using centos repo

Tags: centos, rvm, redhat

How to install rvm(ruby) on RHL7 using centos repo.

I know if we are using centos repository we should be using centos OS and not RedHat, but we have a proprietary software that require Redhat.

when I try to install ruby 1.93 using rvm I got this:

```
rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: redhat/6/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p551.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for redhat.
Unable to locate SystemId file. Is this system registered?
```

Our client does not have registered system with redhat, So I did configure centos repository.

But how can I tell RVM to use this centos repository?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed the problem running:

```
rvm autolibs read-only
```

In that way rvm do not try to download the dependencies from redhat. But it tell us what is missing, so we can install what is missing manually with yum install from centos repository.

Answer (score 0):

RedHat uses the concept of software collection to offer update packages for Ruby, Python, etc:
[softwarecollections](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/user/rhscl/)

For your case, they have software collection for [Ruby193](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/ruby193/) and [Ruby22](https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/rh-ruby22/).

On each page you will find instructions on how to use it.